# Passing an object as a parameter in openrasta get method

Tags: c#, api, rest, openrasta

Is it possible for an OpenRasta handler to have accept a resource as a parameter.
For a URI of (for example) "/search/" could I pass something like:

```
public class SearchRequest
{
  public string Term { get; set; }
  public string[] Categories { get; set; }
  public int LimitPerPage { get; set; }
  public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
}
```

In my handler, have something like:

```
public List<SearchResult> Get(SearchRequest request)
```

Or am I better composing my URI with those as parameters for the querystring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a GET you'll have to declare the parameters you expect in the URI. You can simply have /search?page={CurrentPage} declared in `AtUri`.